# Import contacts: can't get past the "Choose Data Source" screen

Tags: contacts, import

I am trying to import contacts into our database from a CSV file.  On the first import screen, "Choose Data Source", I have set the data source to CSV, picked the file, ticked "first row contains column headers", set contact type to Individual, dup to Update, picked the rule I want to use, set comma separator and the date format.

However, when I click Continue, the same page reloads and everything I had set is cleared.  I am not taken to the next step and I do not see any error message.

Any advice?

Thanks very much,
Richard

Comment: If you try it with a different CSV file do you get the same result?  What version of CiviCRM are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.  The CSV file was malformed.  I rebuilt it and it worked perfectly.
Richard